# I fixed one of my questions, is this the proper way of editing a question for the better of the community helping to lift the question ban?

Tags: discussion, new-users, first-post-review

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840190/why-is-the-so-memory-expensive-compared-to-the-summation-algorithm) , I included a question which I tried editing so that it will be better. I have tried consulting the Help Forums and for the first time people. I'm just posting here if this could be considered an example of question editing, as seen in the edits, that might be able to be used for future reference as either a good or bad edit.

Comment: If your question is *"is that now a valid question?"* then: no. It's not even a question any more! I wouldn't consider that to be fixed and I doubt it will help you attract up votes and get unbanned.

Comment: What are some suggestible ways to edit it and be a valid question?